# BigQuery SQL - Increment ID based on condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sorted table with one field containing true and false values. I want to add an ID type field which increments each time a true value occurs:

[image]

How would I go about doing this? Can I store some kind of variable for Group ID or would I need to somehow back query the previous row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sum` window function with a `case` expression to do this.

```
select t.*,sum(case when condition='TRUE' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by somecolumn) as groupid
from tbl t
```

Answer (score 3):

to eliminate relatively heavy `sum(case when ...)` - you can use `countif` as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, COUNTIF(condition) OVER(ORDER BY pos) AS groupid
FROM `yourTable`
```

you can play with this using your dummy data as in below .

```
#standardSQL
WITH `yourTable` AS (
  SELECT TRUE AS condition, 1 AS `group`, 1 AS pos UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 1, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 1, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUE, 2, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 2, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 2, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 2, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUE, 3, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 3, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUE, 4, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUE, 5, 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 5, 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 5, 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT FALSE, 5, 14  
)
SELECT *, COUNTIF(condition) OVER(ORDER BY pos) AS groupid
FROM `yourTable`
```